# Typescript not catching error in assignment to Partial type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

### Problematic Code

In this code I have a call to a dispatch using a reducer model. The issue is that my action type `ActionTypes.POINT_UPDATED` expects a `payload` with shape `{ id: string; newValues: Partial<A_or_B> }`, yet I can assign properties to `newValues` that do not belong in every constituent of the union defining `A_or_B` (property `color` only exists on `B`, not `A`).

If I assign `newValues` to an object declared inline, the issue exists. If I declare a variable of type `Partial<A_or_B>` then imperatively add properties to that variable, I am prohibited from adding properties that aren't common to every constituent.

**The code below shows two seemingly identical actions, but one is blocked by TS and the other is not. Why is this happening and how can I enforce the proper type constraints?**

[CodeSandbox Link Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-with-partial-types-ch45i?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AppDispatchContext } from "../src/AppProvider";
import { ActionTypes, A_or_B } from "./interfaces";

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useContext(AppDispatchContext);

  const x: Partial<A_or_B> = {};
  // Property 'color' does not exist on type
  // 'Partial<A> | Partial<B>'.
  // Property 'color' does not exist on type 'Partial<A>'.
  x.color = "red";

  dispatch({
    type: ActionTypes.POINT_UPDATED,
    // why can I assign a color to Partial<A>|Partial<B> if 'color'
    // only exists on B?
    payload: { id: "x", newValues: { color: "red" } }
  });
}
```

### Types/Interfaces

```
export type MyState = {
  a: A;
  b: B;
};

export type ActionMap<M extends { [index: string]: any }> = {
  [Key in keyof M]: M[Key] extends undefined
    ? {
        type: Key;
      }
    : {
        type: Key;
        payload: M[Key];
      };
};

export enum ActionTypes {
  POINT_UPDATED = "POINT_UPDATED"
}

export type Payload<T> = {
  [ActionTypes.POINT_UPDATED]: {
    id: string;
    category: Category;
    newValues: Partial<T>;
  };
};

export type Actions<T extends A_or_B> = ActionMap<Payload<T>>[keyof ActionMap<
  Payload<T>
>];

export enum Category {
  A,
  B
}

export interface HasId {
  readonly id: string;
}

export interface Common extends HasId {
  elevation: number;
  fetchTimestamp: number;
}

export interface A extends Common {
  readonly category: Category.A;
}

export interface B extends Common {
  readonly category: Category.B;
  color: string;
}

export type A_or_B = A | B;
```

### Dispatch Definition

```
const AppDispatchContext = createContext<Dispatch<Actions<A_or_B>>>(() => {});
const AppStateContext = createContext<MyState>(initialAppState);

export { AppDispatchContext, AppStateContext };
```